# BlocListener does not listen from Current screen

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I am new to Flutter and using Block for state management. I have two screens

1. RegistrationScreen
2. VerifyScreen

In 'RegistrationScreen' I have added my BlockConsumer as below

```
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            BlocConsumer<RegistrationCubit, RegistrationState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return state.maybeWhen(null,
                    setUpRegistration: () =>
                        createRegistrationForm(context),
                    orElse: () {
                      return createRegistrationForm(context);
                    });
              },
              listener: (context, state) {
                state.maybeWhen(null,
                    registrationInProgress: () => {
                          showLoader(true),
                        },
                    registrationResponseReceived: (response) =>
                        requestForOTPOnSuccess(context, response),
                    registrationFailedGeneric: () =>
                        registrationFailureGeneric(
                            context,
                            "Error in registration",
                            "Something went wrong"),
                    orElse: () {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Once we receive success from service we push to 'VerifyScreen' from 'RegistrationScreen'

And in 'VerifyScreen' I am trying to reuse RegistrationCubit in a BlockListner as below (Call Registration service again on a button click)

```
        BlocListener<RegistrationCubit, RegistrationState>(
          listener: (context, st) {
            st.maybeWhen(null,
                registrationInProgress: () => {
                      showLoader(true),
                    },
                registrationResponseReceived: (_) => showGenericAlert(
                    context,
                    'My App',
                    'Code sent mobile number.'),
                registrationFailedGeneric: () => showGenericAlert(context,
                    'Error', 'An error occurred. Please try again later.'),
                orElse: () {});
          },
          child: Container(),
        )
```

But instead of calling 'VerifyScreen' BlocListener,  'RegistrationScreen' listeners are being called.

Could you please guide why 'RegistrationScreen' listeners are being called from 'VerifyScreen'?